# AWS route 53 redirecting

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created static site in aws s3 example.com and created clouldfront url with SSL then created a record in route 53 example.com and pointed to  clouldfront

Its available in browser - https://example.com but not available in https://www.example.com

Now I want to get same site in https://**www**.example.com

Can i create new record in route 53 [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and it redirect to https://example.com (I tried this but not worked)

Comment: May be this should help you? https://serverfault.com/questions/454977/how-do-i-redirect-www-to-non-www-in-route53